# Parsing string in TurtleSyntax to OWLClass

Tags: owl, owl-api, rdfs, turtle-rdf

Currently I am trying to create OWLClass from a string in Turtle syntax by first creating Jena OntModel and visiting each statement within the class. Is there a better way to create OWL Class using OWL API from Turtle syntax? Below is the string which I am trying to parse.

```
@prefix p0:    <http://rdf.test.com/dl_reasoning/> .
@prefix p1:    <http://rdf.test.com/ns/test_rm#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

p0:safetyGoal_1  a       rdfs:Class , p1:SafetyGoal ;
    rdfs:subClassOf  p1:SafetyGoal ;
    p1:fulfilledBy   p0:fsr_fuel , p0:fsr_coo .

p0:safetyGoal_3  a       rdfs:Class , p1:SafetyGoalVersion ;
    rdfs:subClassOf  p1:SafetyGoal ;


p0:safetyGoal_2  a       rdfs:Class , p1:SafetyGoalVersion ;
    rdfs:subClassOf  p1:SafetyGoal ;
    p1:fulfilledBy   p0:fsr_fuel ;
    p1:fulfills      p0:fsr_coo .
```

Comment: An OWL class is just made by giving a URI (or to be more precise, an IRI), I don't know what you mean by "from Turtle"...are you sure that you mean OWL class? And what means "each statement within the class" - are you still sure that you mean an OWL class? You know the difference between an OWL class and an OWL ontology?

Comment: Yeah. what I meant to say is that I tried to perform query from triple store which I get back in the turtle syntax. I need to read each statement from this result and add those to the ontology, based on the property read. Am i still missing something?

Comment: Which query? A `SELECT` query does **not** return Turtle syntax for sure.

Comment: Its a select query and I am using REST-ful API for this purpose. I am currently using HttpEntity to convert the string to OntModel later and read each class separately and make OWL Classes out of it.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're doing. A `CONSTRUCT` query would return proper RDF e.g. in Turtle format. That means, you'd have RDF triples.

Comment: Anyways, creating an OWL class in OWL API needs an `IRI`, nothing more nothing less.

Comment: Please add an example of the turtle syntax you want to parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you're trying to parse does not contain just classes - it contains axioms as well. In order to be a full ontology, it only lacks an ontology declaration. It should be possible to parse this straight to an ontology - which would be anonymous - by parsing it with one of the Turtle parsers in OWLAPI.

Have you tried parsing this to an `OWLOntology`?

```
String in = "...";
StringDocumentSource input = new StringDocumentSource(in);
OWLOntologyManager m = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
OWLOntology o = m.loadOntologtFromOntologyDocument(input);
```

Listing the axioms or iterating through the signature of the ontology should provide you with enough structure to move forward in your work.

Side note: these two lines seem to be missing a dot:

```
p0:safetyGoal_3  a       rdfs:Class , p1:SafetyGoalVersion ;
rdfs:subClassOf  p1:SafetyGoal ;
```

There should be a full stop to allow parsing:

```
p0:safetyGoal_3  a       rdfs:Class , p1:SafetyGoalVersion ;
rdfs:subClassOf  p1:SafetyGoal .
```

Comment: It works, but I have a couple of questions : it throws the below warnings `[main] WARN org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.SAXParsers - http://www.oracle.com/xml/jaxp/properties/entityExpansionLimit not supported by parser type org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl, error message: Property 'http://www.oracle.com/xml/jaxp/properties/entityExpansionLimit' is not recognized.
[main] WARN org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.SAXParsers - entityExpansionLimit not supported by parser type org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl, error message: Property 'entityExpansionLimit' is not recognized.`

Comment: Also I wanted the properties like _fulfills_ to be read in object property. Right now, its being read as **AnnotationPropertyHierarchy**. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: The warning is to do with the XML libraries you have on the classpath, you can ignore it - it's only for XML parsing.

Comment: To get object properties they need to be declared as such, e.g., op rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty. must be added to the string for op to be an object property.

Comment: Great. Thanks @Ignazio